# SQL select all records only if the sum is greater than 100

Tags: sql, sum

I'm not exactly sure how to ask this so I'll give an example

I have a huge table that resembles something like this...

```
Name Widgets TransDate  Location
Abby  2      12/1/2010  Middleton
Abby  13     1/10/2011  Burmingham
Bobby 10     12/12/2011 Easton
Bobby 5      10/10/2011 Weston
.
.
```

And my current sql statement is...

```
SELECT name, widgets, TransDate, Location 
FROM MyTable
WHERE TransDate BETWEEN 1/1/2011 and 12/31/2011
```

to give me a table like this...

```
Name Widgets TransDate  Location
Abby  13     1/10/2011  Burmingham
Bobby 15     12/12/2011 Easton
Bobby 5      10/10/2011 Weston
.
.
```

How do I modify the above SQL to also get rid of the records of people who do not meet a Widget quota X... say X = 16.  In this case, Abby would be dropped because her total # of widgets is 13 and Bobby's records would stay because his total is 20.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do they need to meet the quota inside `1/1/2011 and 12/31/2011` or at any time

Comment: I need them inside the quota, so I needed the date range in both locations

Comment: Then you'll need to either use SQLMenance's answer or modify Michael's sql to include a WHERE clause in the subquery

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If I understand your request, you want similar results to what you've already got, but filtering for those names who have met the quota.  If that is correct, you can use an `IN()` subquery to find names grouped with >= 100 widgets.

```
SELET name, widgets, TransDate, Location FROM MyTable 
WHERE
  /* IN() subquery for names meeting the quota */
  name IN (
     SELECT name 
     FROM tbl 
     /* If they must have met the quota only during the time window, uncomment below */
     /* Otherwise, omit the WHERE clause to find those who have met the quota at any time */
     /* WHERE TransDate BETWEEN '1/1/2011' and '12/31/2011' */
     GROUP BY name 
     HAVING SUM(widgets) >= 100

  ) 
  AND TransDate BETWEEN '1/1/2011' and '12/31/2011'
```

Comment: you need to add the `TransDate BETWEEN 1/1/2011 and 12/31/2011` to the subquery as well otherwise you will return people with a sum > 16 if they had widgets outside that time frame

Comment: Awesome! Thank you guys for the extremely quick response.  I will try this and let you know how it turns out.  Unfortunately my query is a little more complex then the simple one I posted, so it will take a little time to implement.

Comment: Thank you very much, that worked! I had to put the WHERE TransDate clause in both sections to get the required data.

Answer (score 5):

for sql server it could be done like this

```
SELECT m.name, m.widgets, m.TransDate, m.Location 
FROM MyTable m
JOIN(SELECT name, SUM(widgets) 
            FROM  MyTable 
            WHERE TransDate BETWEEN '1/1/2011' and '12/31/2011'
            GROUP BY NAME 
            HAVING SUM(widgets) >= 16) x
ON x.NAME = m.NAME
WHERE m.TransDate BETWEEN '1/1/2011' and '12/31/2011'
```

Answer (score 1):

For SQL Server 2005+ you could also try:

```
SELECT name, widgets, TransDate, Location
FROM (
       SELECT name, widgets, TransDate, Location, SUM(widgets) OVER(PARTITION BY Name) Quant
       FROM MyTable
       WHERE TransDate BETWEEN 1/1/2011 and 12/31/2011) A
WHERE Quant >= 16
```

This is assuming that the quota must be meeted on the same date frame.